# Remove all pixels with all-zero neighbors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ndimage

Is there a way to perform a process similar to erosion in OpenCV that retains a given pixel if **ANY** of its neighbors are non-zero, instead of requiring all of its neighbors to be non-zero?

Here, by neighbors, I mean any pixel with `abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)==1`, but that is easy to control via the erosion kernel.

Of course, I can always use for loops and implement this behavior from scratch, but I prefer the speed that OpenCV can provide with its libraries.

Will it work to invert the image, perform an erosion, and then invert it back?

The other idea I had would be to convolve with a kernel with an empty center and then clip all values to the range 0 to 1. I would use `scipy.ndimage.convolve` for this.

I am working with a binary NumPy array with type `np.float32` (i.e., values of 0.0 or 1.0) with shape (512,512).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to accomplish your goal would be to convolve with a square 3x3 kernel of ones. For each pixel, you now know how many foreground pixels there are in its neighborhood (including itself). Threshold this at 2 (`>= 2`) to get all pixels where there are at least 2 foreground pixels in the neighborhood. Finally, the logical AND with the original image will give all foreground pixels that have at least one foreground neighbor.

Here's an example:

```py
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
                [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=np.float32)
tmp = scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant')
out = np.logical_and(tmp >= 2, img).astype(np.float32)
```

The output is:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

---

Of course some imaging libraries will have functions designed specifically for this purpose. I don't know if OpenCV or ndimage or scikit-image have such a function, I don't know these libraries well enough. [But DIPlib does](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-GetSinglePixels-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-String-CL) (disclosure: I'm an author):

```py
import diplib as dip

out = img - dip.GetSinglePixels(img > 0)
```

The `img > 0` part is to convert the floating-point array into a logical array, which DIPlib expects for binary images. This is about 5 times as fast as the other solution for a 512x512 image.

Comment: are you sure that `scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant')` does not need to have the origin variable specified? I would use `scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant',origin=(1,1))`, am I wrong?

Comment: @MichaelSohnen Do you get a different output if you do that? I seemed to get the right output with the code I wrote, so I don't think it's necessary to specify the origin. I would expect that the middle of the kernel is the default origin.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen The docs say that `origin=0` (the default) causes the kernel to be centered around the middle pixel. Setting `origin=(1,1)` would shift the kernel to the left and up.

Comment: Okay, I read the docs wrong. In a previous project I had used origin=(1,1,1) for a 3d convolution but I guess it was incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Luengo I used your first solution (with some adaptation) for a similar task on a 3D numpy array. I got the results I needed with no perceivable performance issues. Thank you for the help. Also I like how your algorithm can be adapted. If instead of using the logical and, you use a comparison (e.g. `img[tmp<3]=0.0`), it is possible to remove pixels with varying levels of strandedness. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have

```py
src = np.uint8([
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

(you can figure out how to get that from your floats)

You are looking for nonzero pixels where *not* all neighbors are 0. You could construct the *desired result* from *several* operations.

You can use **[`MORPH_HITMISS`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d06/tutorial_hitOrMiss.html)** for the positive condition (all neighbors 0), then combine with the negation.

You'd use this kernel:

```py
kernel = np.int8([ # 0 means "don't care", all others have to match
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [-1, +1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1],
])

neighbors_all_zero = cv.morphologyEx(src=src, op=cv.MORPH_HITMISS, kernel=kernel)

result = src & ~neighbors_all_zero
```

Result:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Be careful with the values themselves. OpenCV assumes masks to be 0 or 255 sometimes, and 0 and non-zero at other times. I got some funny results when I used just 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 255. I'm sure those can be worked with though.

Comment: sure, but what do you think about simply clipping the result of scipy convolution with a kernel with an empty center and 1.0s for the neighbors?

Comment: I can give this solution a try, but I may try the others first since they do not require changing the type of my array

Comment: his solution assumes that you have exactly 0.0 and 1.0 values. if you don't have exactly that, you **still** need thresholding/comparison to arrive at a **mask**, and then convolution on floats is more expensive than what I do here. in any case, convolution on floats probably costs more than this morphology approach on integers. you should benchmark it if you care about performance. if you care about results, don't.